# How to get ordinal Weekdays in a Month

Tags: java, date, ordinal, localdate

hi i want to make a program in java where days,weekNo is parameter ..Like First Friday of the month or second Monday of the month ..and it returns the date

Answer (score 5):

Here's a utility method that does that, using [`DateUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/time/DateUtils.html) from [Apache Commons / Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang):

```
/**
 * Get the n-th x-day of the month in which the specified date lies.  
 * @param input the specified date
 * @param weeks 1-based offset (e.g. 1 means 1st week)
 * @param targetWeekDay (the weekday we're looking for, e.g. Calendar.MONDAY
 * @return the target date
 */
public static Date getNthXdayInMonth(final Date input,
    final int weeks,
    final int targetWeekDay){

    // strip all date fields below month
    final Date startOfMonth = DateUtils.truncate(input, Calendar.MONTH);
    final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(startOfMonth);
    final int weekDay = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    final int modifier = (weeks - 1) * 7 + (targetWeekDay - weekDay);
    return modifier > 0
        ? DateUtils.addDays(startOfMonth, modifier)
        : startOfMonth;
}
```

**Test code:**

```
// Get this month's third thursday
System.out.println(getNthXdayInMonth(new Date(), 3, Calendar.THURSDAY));

// Get next month's second wednesday:
System.out.println(getNthXdayInMonth(DateUtils.addMonths(new Date(), 1),
    2,
    Calendar.WEDNESDAY)
);
```

**Output:**

> Thu Nov 18 00:00:00 CET 2010
>   Wed Dec 08 00:00:00 CET 2010

---

And here's a [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) version of the same code (I've never used JodaTime before, so there's probably a simpler way to do it):

```
/**
 * Get the n-th x-day of the month in which the specified date lies.
 * 
 * @param input
 *            the specified date
 * @param weeks
 *            1-based offset (e.g. 1 means 1st week)
 * @param targetWeekDay
 *            (the weekday we're looking for, e.g. DateTimeConstants.MONDAY
 * @return the target date
 */
public static DateTime getNthXdayInMonthUsingJodaTime(final DateTime input,
    final int weeks,
    final int targetWeekDay){

    final DateTime startOfMonth =
        input.withDayOfMonth(1).withMillisOfDay(0);
    final int weekDay = startOfMonth.getDayOfWeek();
    final int modifier = (weeks - 1) * 7 + (targetWeekDay - weekDay);
    return modifier > 0 ? startOfMonth.plusDays(modifier) : startOfMonth;
}
```

**Test Code:**

```
// Get this month's third thursday
System.out.println(getNthXdayInMonthUsingJodaTime(new DateTime(),
    3,
    DateTimeConstants.THURSDAY));

// Get next month's second wednesday:
System.out.println(getNthXdayInMonthUsingJodaTime(new DateTime().plusMonths(1),
    2,
    DateTimeConstants.WEDNESDAY));
```

**Output:**

> 2010-11-18T00:00:00.000+01:00
>   2010-12-08T00:00:00.000+01:00

Answer (score 2):

```
  public static Date getDate(int day, int weekNo, int month, int year) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.DATE,1);
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
    for (int i = 0; i < 31; i++) {
        if (cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH) == weekNo
                && cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == day) {
            return cal.getTime();
        }
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE,1);
    }
    return null;
  }
```

**Calling code**

```
System.out.println(""+getDate(Calendar.MONDAY, 2, Calendar.DECEMBER,2010));
```

**Output**

```
Mon Dec 06 15:09:00 IST 2010
```

- [Resource](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html)
- [Also look at Joda Time it is better](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: I formatted the code and fixed the syntax errors. But there's still a huge bug in there that you should fix (hint: just try to run this)

Comment: Joda Time is not only better: JODA TIME ROCKS FOR DATE/TIME OPERATIONS

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate firstFridayThisMonth =
    LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) )
             .with( TemporalAdjusters.firstInMonth( DayOfWeek.FRIDAY ) )
```

## Using java.time

The other Answers are now outdated. The troublesome old date-time classes (`Date`, `Calendar`, etc.) are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the java.time classes.

## `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z );
```

## `TemporalAdjuster`

The [`TemporalAdjuster`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjuster.html) interface provides for manipulating date-time values. The java.time classes use immutable objects, so the result is always a fresh new object with values based on the original.

The [`TemporalAdjusters`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html) class (note plural name) provides several handy implementations. Amongst those are ones to get ordinal day-of-week within the month: `firstInMonth()`, `lastInMonth()`, and [`dayOfWeekInMonth()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html#dayOfWeekInMonth-int-java.time.DayOfWeek-). All of these take an argument of a `DayOfWeek` enum object.

```
LocalDate firstFridayOfThisMonth = 
    today.with(
        TemporalAdjusters.firstInMonth( DayOfWeek.FRIDAY ) 
    )
;
```

…and…

```
LocalDate secondMondayOfThisMonth = 
    today.with(
        TemporalAdjusters.dayOfWeekInMonth( 2 , DayOfWeek.MONDAY ) 
    )
;
```

…and…

```
LocalDate thirdWednesdayOfNextMonth = 
    today.plusMonths( 1 )
         .with(  
             TemporalAdjusters.dayOfWeekInMonth( 3 , DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY )  
         )
;
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri I very often close Questions as duplicates, especially for date-time questions. I invite you to do the same. This case, however, is *not* a duplicate. While these two share the topic of the ordinal day-of-week in month, they are not the same. The other Question is for Android. The other Question involves looping and collecting a series of dates. The other Question involves `EnumSet`, `List`, and `YearMonth`, none of which is mentioned here. This Answer shows multiple TemporalAdjusters, the other, only one. I do copy-paste some chunks of boilerplate, but not entire answers.

Answer (score -1):

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
int dayofweek = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
```

this should do what you want.
**edit**:
with some more calculate steps, you could have result :) (sorry for confuse your title)