# JodaTime equivalent of DateUtils.truncate()

Tags: java, jodatime

I have never used [JodaTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) before, but answering this question, [How to get ordinal Weekdays in a Month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4131558/how-to-get-weekdays-in-a-month/4132083#4132083).

I tried it and came up with this ugly code to unset all fields below day:

```
DateTime startOfMonth =
    input.withDayOfMonth(1)
        .withHourOfDay(0)       // there
        .withMinuteOfHour(0)    // has got to
        .withSecondOfMinute(0)  // be a shorter way
        .withMillisOfSecond(0); // to do this
```

Where the [Commons / Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang) equivalent using [DateUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/time/DateUtils.html) would be

```
Date startOfMonth = DateUtils.truncate(input, Calendar.MONTH);
```

What's the preferred idiom to do that in JodaTime?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can use **[roundFloorCopy()](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.Property.html#roundFloorCopy%28%29)** to mimic DateUtils.truncate

```
Date truncateMonth = DateUtils.truncate(input, Calendar.MONTH);
-> DateTime truncateMonth = input.dayOfMonth().roundFloorCopy();

Date truncateMinute = DateUtils.truncate(input, Calendar.MINUTE);
-> DateTime truncateMinute = input.minuteOfDay().roundFloorCopy();

Date truncateHourOfDay = DateUtils.truncate(input, Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
-> DateTime truncateHourOfDay = input.hourOfDay().roundFloorCopy()
```

Comment: By far the best in my opinion.  I needed the date to be "rounded" by something selected by the user.  Using [code]input.property(<DateTimeFieldType>).roundFloorCopy()[/code] saved a lot of custom coding.

Answer (score 42):

**Use the `withMillisOfDay()` method to shorten the syntax.**

```java
DateTime startOfMonth = input.withDayOfMonth(1).withMillisOfDay(0);
```

Comment: Bozho's answer is probably the "official" solution, but I like this one better. Thanks.

Comment: Why would you think that?  I don't get it.  I like this one better too, because it requires the minimum number of objects to be created.

Comment: Why would I think that? Because a dedicated class exists for this exact kind of problem.

Comment: I would say that the `withMillisOfDay` method exists for this exact kind of problem.  The `DateMidnight` class exists for some other kind of problem, where you want to keep references to those objects around.  It's silly to use another class just to have to convert it back immediately -- especially when the class you were working with has a method that does exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: both answers each construct the same number of objects

Answer (score 21):

Take a look at [`DateMidnight`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateMidnight.html).

```
DateTime startOfMonth = new DateTime(new DateMidnight(input.withDayOfMonth(1)));
```

Update: 2013-08-16 by JodaStephen: Version 2.3 of Joda-Time deprecates `DateMidnight` as it was a very bad idea of a class.

So use:

```
DateTime startOfMonth = input.withDayOfMonth(1).withTimeAtStartOfDay();
```

Comment: so I guess you mean this: `new DateMidnight(new DateTime())`

Comment: @Erick true, but IMHO not a reason for a downvote. This is still a good answer

Comment: I don't understand why this is a better answer than using `withMillisOfDay(0)`.  A `DateMidnight` object is not a `DateTime` object, so an extra object needs to be created this way.

Comment: DateMidnight should be avoided, as it has dodgy semantics (not all locations have midnight on DST change days). Use LocalDate instead of DateMidnight. The intended mechanism for this in Joda-Time is roundFloorCopy(), Soundlinks answer.

Answer (score 1):

Joda Time also supports the [withFields](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/src-html/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#line.775) method in the `DateTime` type. This can also be used to create a short syntax:

```
new DateTime().withDayOfMonth(1).withFields(new LocalTime(0, 0));
```

In production code the argument to `withFields` should be factored out to a constant.