# which timezone is used by DateUtils?

Tags: java, apache-commons

I'm trying to use `DateUtils` from `apache-commons3`, but can't understand which timezone it relies on:

```
Date date = DateUtils.truncate(date, Calendar.DATE);
```

How does it know which timezone I'm in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The timezone which is the default of your computer.  Looking at the [source code](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang///javadocs/api-2.6/src-html/org/apache/commons/lang/time/DateUtils.html#line.814), it does this:

```
    public static Date truncate(Date date, int field) {
        if (date == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The date must not be null");
        }
        Calendar gval = Calendar.getInstance();
        gval.setTime(date);
        modify(gval, field, MODIFY_TRUNCATE);
        return gval.getTime();
    }
```

The documentation of [Calendar.getInstance()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getInstance%28%29) says:  Gets a calendar using the default time zone and locale.

If you're willing to switch to JodaTime instead, here's a way do the same thing in JodaTime: [JodaTime equivalent of DateUtils.truncate()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133682/jodatime-equivalent-of-dateutils-truncate)