# Joda time round to days

Tags: java, jodatime

Basically what I need is round any date to days. For example:
2014-01-01 14:00:00 should be converted to 2014-01-01.

I was trying to achieve it using `DateTimeFormatter` but was not able to find a method which would return me an actual joda `object` but not a String.

Comment: You want to truncate the date. I think this answer will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133682/jodatime-equivalent-of-dateutils-truncate

Comment: So your input is a string (e.g. `"2014-01-01 14:00:00"`) and you want the result to be a [`LocalDate`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html)? If not, which Joda object type did you desire?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
DateTime d = DateTime.now();
LocalDate ld = new LocalDate(d);
```

The local date will contain only year, month date