# How to find out adjusted hour in scala

Tags: scala

I have some examples:

- case1. `val date1 = new DateTime("2015-08-03T04:59:00.000")`

  output: `new DateTime("2015-08-03T04:00:00.000")`
- case2. `val date2 = new DateTime("2015-08-03T04:15:00.000")`

  output: `new DateTime("2015-08-03T04:00:00.000")`

means for any datetime if the time is more the 1 minute output should be start of hour. Example for day: `datetime.withTimeAtStartOfDay`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JodaTime equivalent of DateUtils.truncate()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133682/jodatime-equivalent-of-dateutils-truncate)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you are using the joda time `DateTime`.  If you are, then you can use the following method

```
def dateTimeAtStartOfHour(s: String) = {
  new DateTime(s)
    .withMinuteOfHour(0)
    .withSecondOfMinute(0)
    .withMillisOfSecond(0)
}

val date1 = dateTimeAtStartOfHour("2015-08-03T04:59:00.000")
val date2 = dateTimeAtStartOfHour("2015-08-03T04:15:00.000")
val date3 = dateTimeAtStartOfHour("2015-08-03T04:59:13.000")
```

Output is

> date1: org.joda.time.DateTime = 2015-08-03T04:00:00.000-04:00
>
> date2: org.joda.time.DateTime = 2015-08-03T04:00:00.000-04:00
>
> date3: org.joda.time.DateTime = 2015-08-03T04:00:00.000-04:00

Answer (score 0):

You need to use "truncate" analogue, which is called `roundFloorCopy` in joda:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8510936/1349366